# How to validate web page response code opened from linked text button in desktop application

Tags: python, pywinauto

How to validate that the online content is opened in default browser like Edge, IE or Chrome.
Steps:
1.  Open notepad
2.  Click Help-->View Help
3.  View Help content opened in Edge browser

```
app = Application().start("notepad.exe")
time.sleep(2)
app.UntitledNotepad.menu_select("Help->View Help")
```

[Screenshot for child process of Edge browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7Gi2.png)

Answer (score 1):

May I ask what are you trying to accomplish? If you want automation on web pages, you best use selenium see [documentation](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)

Comment: Thanks Joe for your response, but in my case, open notepad navigate to help menu click on view Help, On click on View help menu it will open in default browsers like IE/Edge. so my problem is, how i can switch control from windows notepad to launched browser(IE/Edge)

Comment: Oh I see, you want to automate what happens on the page that opens when you clicked the view help in the help tab on notepad. I don't think `pywinauto` has that fuctionality. I may be wrong though. But for the sake of giving an idea how to proceed. Have you considered, again, `selenium`?. As this does web automation. From what I understand, you just have to copy this link `https://www.bing.com/search?q=get+help+with+notepad+in+windows+10&filters=guid:%224466414-en-dia%22%20lang:%22en%22&form=T00032&ocid=HelpPane-BingIA` place it in `selenium` to do automation on it :)).

Comment: That link is where the view help button directs you when you click it. So in `selenium` you just start there? I hope this helps, don't forget to upvote :)) cheers man

Comment: Hi Joe, Is it possible to get the detail of child process using python(psutil) library for example Edge or IE browser in task manager?